support TPU as accelerator on dataflow worker
Is there support or plan to support TPU as accelerator in dataflow (classic or prime) worker? From the doc, it seems only GPU is supported at the moment.

Wouldn't it be better to ask Google this?

From the available documentation and resources, it appears that Google Cloud Dataflow currently supports GPUs as accelerators but does not explicitly mention support for TPUs (Tensor Processing Units). The focus on accelerators in Dataflow documentation and resources primarily highlights GPU support.
For the most accurate and up-to-date information, it's best to check the official Google Cloud Dataflow documentation or reach out to Google Cloud support directly. Here is the link to the Google Cloud Dataflow documentation : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/ .
